how to efficiently check common elements of two lists of different types ( class A and class B) and make a resultant list of type A for all matches
I have a list of class A with 1000 elements that has all unique ids. There is some other Class B , which also has a unique id parameter and this B is a json property of Class A.
the relation is like :
A : {**"id"** :id1,
  **"usedBy"**: {
    "type": "Some ENUM which represents class B",
    "id": "id2",
  }
},

The object B which is used in object A , is an independent and can be deleted externally from some other request as well , which makes dependent A object obsolete/invalid . also there can be many other objects of type B in system and not all of them need to be linked with R type.
The task is to check all such invalid A objects for which dependent B is not exist anymore in system and delete those invalid A periodically.
Can anyone tell a better way to approach this problem , Thanks .
Firstly i have listed all elements of class A in l1 , then listed all the unique Ids of class B which is used in class A in l2.
Now there is a list l3 , in which collected all such invalid ids of class B, which are in l2 but not in ( l1.gentContent().getUsedBy().getId() )
now have the list l3 with all such non existent type B id , and for all these ids , have to delete dependent class A object. But the approach has used many if else and a nested loop , which firstly not seems pretty impressive and also this is not acceptable by software quality checks as only 3 if/else/for allowed in a method.
Can anyone tell a better way to approach this problem , Thanks .
**This is a sample snipped i tried **
public void validateForAutoCleanUp(OperationContext context, Page<class A> page) {

    List<Class A> invalidsToDelete = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Class A> existing = page.getContent().stream().toList();
        
    List<String> usedByIds = page.getContent().stream().map(Class A::getUsedBy).map(UsedBy::getId).toList();
    List<Class B> b = service.getAllofTypeB(context, pageNumber, pageSize, null, null).block();

    if (b != null) {
        List<String> invalidUsedByIds = usedByIds.stream().filter(id -> ! b.stream().map(Class B::getId).toList().contains(id)).toList();
        if (!invalidUsedByIds.isEmpty()) {
            for (Class A a : existing) {
                for (String invalidId : invalidUsedByIds) {
                    if (a.getUsedBy().getId().equals(invalidId)) {
                        invalidsToDelete.add(a);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!invalidsToDelete.isEmpty())
                invalidsToDelete.forEach(i -> service.deleteById(context, i.getId()).block());
        } else {
            page.getContent().forEach(a -> service.deleteById(context, a.getId()).block());
        }
    }
}


To solve your problem more efficiently and reduce the complexity of if and for, you can use Set to allow fast searches and eliminate nested loops.

Use Set for Quick Searches
Eliminate Nested Loops
Reduce Conditionals

Something like this:
public void validateForAutoCleanUp(OperationContext context, Page page) {
    List<ClassA> existing = page.getContent();
    Set<String> usedByIds = existing.stream()
                                     .map(a -> a.getUsedBy().getId())
                                     .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    List<ClassB> classBList = service.getAllofTypeB(context, pageNumber, pageSize, null, null).block();

    if (classBList != null) {
        Set<String> validBIds = classBList.stream()
                                          .map(ClassB::getId)
                                          .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        List<ClassA> invalidsToDelete = existing.stream()
                                                .filter(a -> !validBIds.contains(a.getUsedBy().getId()))
                                                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        invalidsToDelete.forEach(a -> service.deleteById(context, a.getId()).block());
    } else {
        existing.forEach(a -> service.deleteById(context, a.getId()).block());
    }
}


Thank you so much , it seems very readable and precise ,  @Luan Nadaletti
